# WPF Multibinding Converter with MultiData Triggers

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a scenario where a style is set on a border. It has a multidata trigger on it and some of the conditions check properties on the child elements of the border. It looks like this:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=Child.IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True" />
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=CommandBackgroundHover, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ctrl:ExtendedProgressBar}}}"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

I need to add some "or" logic to this so the background also changes if the Child.IsFocused is true. As a test I replaced the current Child.IsEnabled condition with Child.IsFocused and the background changes as expected when the control receives focus. I did some research and found a way to implement the "or" logic I need, however when I do that the Child.IsFocused property is resolving to DependancyProperty.UnsetValue. Here is the modified xaml and converter.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Value="True">
                <Condition.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBoolConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Child.IsFocused" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                        <Binding Path="IsMouseOver" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Condition.Binding>
            </Condition>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=Child.IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True" />
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=CommandBackgroundHover, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ctrl:ExtendedProgressBar}}}"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Here is the converter:

```
public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    try
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
            {
                if (value[i] is bool && (bool)value[i]) { return true; }
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }

    return false;
}
```

I don't see why this is failing. The syntax is obviously slightly different but it looks like it is accomplishing the same thing. Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
After messing with this for a few more hours, I've narrowed the issue down a bit more. In the initial code block I posted, Child.IsEnabled will not resolve if it is thee first condition. The same goes for Child.IsFocused. Either will resolve fine if there are only two conditions and they are placed second. I was able to get it working fine by creating three separate styles and referencing the target Child element by name. Obviously this is less efficient than I'd like but I don't have any idea what would cause this issue.

Comment: See [multidatatrigger with multibinding in ControlTemplate.Triggers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23471902/multidatatrigger-with-multibinding-in-controltemplate-triggers)

Comment: It's close but I don't think that's going to work. It looks like my relative source is set correctly. I edited the opening with a bit more info that may explain better why I need the child. Again this all works fine as a condition outside of the converter.

Comment: You should post [a good, complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably demonstrates the issue. Barring that, can you confirm that by "the Child.IsFocused property is resolving to DependancyProperty.UnsetValue", you mean you have debugged the `Convert()` method and that that is the value of the property you receive? Please also describe what other debugging you've done (i.e. to confirm the flow of values through the binding system), as well as post the XAML for the non-multi-binding test you did with `Child.IsFocused`.

Comment: Most of the information you asked for is in my post. The non multi-binding version is the first code block with Child.IsEnabled switched with Child.IsFocused, which is what I said. It's a simple enough change to visualize without me cluttering the post up with redundant code. As for the "unset" resolve yes I can confirm it through the converter value. I appreciate you taking the time to read my post and write something but you aren't really offering anything in the way of help or direction.